# MongoDB TTL - Where and when?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to use TTL in MongoDB.
That's my function:

```
async function ttl() {
    const collection = await getCollection('game')
    await collection.createIndex({ 'createdAt': 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 120 })
}
```

getCollection function:

```
async function getCollection(collectionName) {
    const db = await connect()
    return db.collection(collectionName);
}
```

connect function:

```
async function connect() {
    if (dbConn) return dbConn;
    try {
        const client = await MongoClient.connect(config.dbURL, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
        const db = client.db(dbName);
        dbConn = db;
        return db;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Cannot Connect to DB', err)
        throw err;
    }
}
```

I want to delete documents after 2 minutes passed from their insert.
I have a `createdAt` for each document (new Date())

**When do I need to "run" the function? Tried to use IIFE in my db.service..**

**and where do I need to "run" the function?**

Thanks for helping...!

Comment: Are you connecting to DB everytime a collection is required?

Comment: @Ravi Shankar I don’t understand you question, can you look at my code please?

Comment: What function do you want to run? You need to create that index once. You can do that through a DB admin UI or as part of your installation/migration script, your application does not do it at runtime, it is a one-time thing during deployment.

Comment: @Thilo I'm sorry but I don't understand. Tried to run this: db.getCollection('game').createIndex( { "createdAt": 1 }, { expireAfterSeconds: 10 } ) on my Robo 3T, and it still not working. what do I need to do after I create the index?

Comment: What is not working? The index was not created? The documents you added to the collection were not deleted? Also note that the job that deletes expired documents is only run once a minute, so it can take up to 70 seconds for your documents to be deleted.

Comment: @Thilo I think the index was created but the documents not deleted: https://i.ibb.co/T8qKzRg/mongodb.jpg